# How to update users new_password in reset password system?

Tags: php, pdo

I am creating reset password system, Iam done with all parts accept last step where updating password and email in users table.
actually where it doesn't update.lol

it says update succes and redirecting to login but doesn't update pasword.
I echoed all steps to see if values are empty it shows all full.

This is my form:

```
$selector = $_GET["selector"];
$validator = $_GET["validator"];
if(empty($selector) || empty($validator)){
    echo "Could not validate request";
}else{
    if(ctype_xdigit($selector) !== false && ctype_xdigit($validator) !== false){
    ?>
    <form action="reset-password.inc.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="selector" value="<?php echo $selector; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="validator" value="<?php echo $validator; ?>">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Yeni şifre girin...">
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Şifre tekrar...">
        <input type="submit" name="reset-password-submit" value="Submit">
        <a class="btn btn-link" href="welcome.php">Cancel</a>
    </form>     
    <?php   
    }
}
```

And this is the codes in submit page:

```
if(isset($_POST["reset-password-submit"])){

$selector = $_POST["selector"];
$validator = $_POST["validator"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$confirm_password = $_POST["confirm_password"];
$currentDate = date("U"); 

    if(empty($password) && empty($confirm_password)){
        header("Location: create-new-password.php?newpwd=empty");
        exit();
    }elseif($password != $confirm_password){
        header("Location: create-new-password.php?newpwd=passwords-not-same");
        exit();
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdResetSelector = :pwdResetSelector AND pwdResetToken = :pwdResetToken AND pwdResetExpires >= :pwdResetExpires";
        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->bindParam(":pwdResetSelector", $selector, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pwdResetToken", $validator, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pwdResetExpires", $currentDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($selector !== $row['pwdResetSelector']){
                header("Location: create-new-password.php?newpwd=wrongUrlParameters");
                exit();
            }elseif($validator !== $row['pwdResetToken']){
                header("Location: create-new-password.php?newpwd=wrongUrlParameters");
                exit();
            }else{
                $tokenEmail = $row["pwdResetEmail"];

                // CHECK IF EMPTY PASS AND EMAIL AND DO UPDATE

                if(empty($password) && empty($tokenEmail)){
                    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE email=:email";
                    if($stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
                        $newpwdhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $stmt3->bindParam(":password", $newpwdhash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt3->bindParam(":email", $tokenEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        if($stmt3->execute()){

                            // DELETE FROM PWDRESET TABLE
                            $sql = "DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmail=:pwdResetEmail";
                            if($stmt4 = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
                                $stmt4->bindParam(":pwdResetEmail", $tokenEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $stmt4->execute();

                                header("Location: login.php?newpwd=success");
                                exit();
                            }else{
                                header("Location: create-new-password.php?newpwd=somethingWentWrong");
                                exit();
                            }

                        }else{
                            echo "Couldnt execute stmt 3";
                            exit();
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "error";
                        exit();
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "AN ERROR HAPPEND WHILE QUERY STMT 3";
                    exit();
                }
            }
            }else{
                echo "Couldnt execute sql 1";
                exit();
            }
        }else{
            echo "prepare sql didnt work 1";
            exit();
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "something went wrong";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that $tokenEmail has the value you expect? The issue may not be a syntax error, but rather a data error: What you think you're passing in may not be what you're actually passing in. Try substituting the variables for the values in the query and echo it/log it so you can see what's being passed.

Comment: That was the first thing I have checked, when I echo it like `$row['pwdResetEmail']` it works fine, even I used `"pre` function.

Comment: I don't understand this: `if(empty($password) && empty($tokenEmail))` Isn't this backwards?

Comment: no it wasn't I am checking all from the begining again right now and it looks like the problem I dont get values from reset table but why ?

Comment: I got it now its because of the date value `AND pwdResetExpires >= :pwdResetExpires";` How to check for expire date in query ?